# Mathematical notation of a mixed effect model with different variance structures

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, heteroscedasticity, notation

I am assessing the relationship between a response variable (`Y`) and a predictor (`X`) using repeated measures in 6 individuals (factor `ID`). `Y` and `X` are continuous variables and since the distribution of `Y` and `X` is not normal nor the residuals after fitting a LMM, I decided to log-transform `Y` and `X`. Then, compared by AIC the random structure of my model using `1|ID` and `X|ID`, selecting the second option. After that, I specified the variance structure using different functions from the package `nlme` to meet assumptions of homogeneous variance and normal distribution of errors by means of the AIC. The better variance function in my case was `varPower(form= ~ log(X)|ID)`. Finally, I compared the AIC for different LMMs using different polynomials of log(`X`), to check if the relationship between `log(Y)` and `log(X)` is linear or exponential.

If I understood well, given that I have only one regressor, the general model can be written as

*y<sub>ij</sub> = β<sub>0</sub> + β<sub>1</sub>x<sub>ij</sub> + u<sub>0j</sub> + u<sub>1j</sub>x<sub>ij</sub> + ϵ<sub>ij</sub>* (**Eq.1**),

where *y<sub>ij</sub>* denotes the i-th observation of group *j* of the response, and *x<sub>ij</sub>* and *ϵ<sub>ij</sub>* the respective predictor and error term.

However, in my case, I have doubts about how I should specify the general model knowing that I used log-transform variables and that I had to set the variance structure using `varPower(form= ~ log(X)|ID)`.

Should I change `Eq.1` to specify those particularities of my LMM?